# Ethernet connection not working ubuntu server Intel 15f3

Tags: networking, drivers, server, ethernet

i have a mini pc and i installed ubuntu server,
i have a ethernet port but is not working i think because the driver is not loaded the hardware of the pc is :

`Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 15f3 (rev 03)`

and if i run this command,  `lshw -C network`  ,  i get

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c1300000-c13fffff memory:c1400000-c1403fff memory:c1200000-c12fffff
```

Some one knows how to solve it ?

Thank you

Comment: It is always helpful to include the version of Ubuntu you are using in any question. What version is being used here?

Comment: Latest version 20.04

Comment: Please use a temporary alternative internet connection (WiFi, USB tethering, etc.) and make sure to fully update the system: `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`. It has been reported that after this all the required drivers/firmware will be installed.

Comment: I did, but still network UNCLAIMED

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my LarkBox X's 15f3 rev 3 ethernet ports. The latest Ubuntu Desktop 21.10, however, works! You can install all the same software on the Desktop that you need for a server. Eventually the LTS Server will catch up with the driver updates, but until that time it's a workaround.